# Остановка секундомера при cкроле таблицы

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, таймер

Ребят такой вопрос. При скроле таблицы зависает секундомер. 
Есть две клавиши:
1. Совмещенная startStopButton 
2. Сбрасывает все записи в таблице и обнуляет Label.

3.Также функция для подсчета времени.
В каком месте я должен использовать `DispatchQueue`, чтобы при cкроле таблица не висла? в методе `cellForRowAt` не помогает. Прикреплю код, может кто знает как помочь.

[image]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Исходники текстом надо добавлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы таймер не останавливался при скролле, необходимо добавить его в `RunLoop`:

```
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
```

---

Ну и для Ваших целей оптимальнее все же будет `CADisplayLink` и пользоваться отрезками времени, а не просто суммировать тики (таймеры не точные, у них довольно большая погрешность).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)